# JSON Object Android placing issue

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I am trying to place this JSON Object in my Listview in android but I am having a problem with json mismatch.

This is the output of my server JSON :

```
{"Patient 0":
{"firstName":"admir","lastName":"andrade","email":"admirmonteiro@live.com"},
    "Patient 1":
{"firstName":"alden","lastName":"andrade","email":"admirmonteiro@yahoo.com"}}
```

In my android code, I have the following code :

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
```

How can I updated my list with both patients information without having to call each object once(if there are many, I don't know how to do this)? What do I need to do further to update my listView with two columns, one for first name and last name and the other with the email, as the JSON output form the server show? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I am not understand you.. can you tell what is your exact problem?

Comment: Convert your json into ArrayList using GSON library.

Comment: Do you mean json library ? @Amy

Comment: @RanjithKumar if I have a list view in android, how can I call or use the json object library  to update my list view as I described above?

Comment: ok I got it.. I give solution soon

Comment: @Aboogie I've updated my answer as well as tested too. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Aboogie r u try my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine,

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result.trim());
Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();

while(keys.hasNext() ) {
    String key = (String)keys.next();
    if (jObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject ) {

         String firstName = ((JSONObject) jObject.get(key)).getString("firstName");
         String lastName = ((JSONObject) jObject.get(key)).getString("lastName");
         String email = ((JSONObject) jObject.get(key)).getString("email");

         Log.d("jsondata","Firstname = "+firstName+"\nlastname = "+lastName+"\nemail = "+email);

    }
}
```

**Update**

Here is the full codes that I tested,

```
    String result = "{\"Patient 0\":{\"firstName\":\"admir\",\"lastName\":\"andrade\",\"email\":\"admirmonteiro@live.com\"},\"Patient 1\":{\"firstName\":\"alden\",\"lastName\":\"andrade\",\"email\":\"admirmonteiro@yahoo.com\"}}";

    JSONObject jObject = null;
    try {
        jObject = new JSONObject(result.trim());
        Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();

        while(keys.hasNext() ) {
            String key = (String)keys.next();
            if (jObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject ) {

                String firstName = ((JSONObject) jObject.get(key)).getString("firstName");
                String lastName = ((JSONObject) jObject.get(key)).getString("lastName");
                String email = ((JSONObject) jObject.get(key)).getString("email");
                Log.d("jsondata","Firstname = "+firstName+"\nlastname = "+lastName+"\nemail = "+email);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I get this error : org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of; this too : at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449) plus more

Comment: may be you are getting blank response, try again and be sure that you received json data.

Comment: awesome Thanks @Shree Krishna

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
      String result ="{\"Patient 0\":\n" +
            "{\"firstName\":\"admir\",\"lastName\":\"andrade\",\"email\":\"admirmonteiro@live.com\"},\n" +
            "    \"Patient 1\":\n" +
            "{\"firstName\":\"alden\",\"lastName\":\"andrade\",\"email\":\"admirmonteiro@yahoo.com\"}}";

    JSONObject data = null;
    try {
        data = new JSONObject(""+result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    List<String> FName = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0 ; i<data.length();i++){

        try {
            JSONObject innerData = data.getJSONObject("Patient "+i);

            FName .add(innerData.getString("firstName"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```